# SQL Select rows based on parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server

so I created a customer table that looks a bit like this

[image]

Each customer is either new, recurring, or reactivated, and each customer can only be one type so whatever type it is has a 1 in that field and a 0 in all other fields.

I am created a report where I want to have a parameter called customer type that lets you select new, recurring, reactivated, and all, and it will show you only the customer type that you select.

I am not sure how to do this.

I have the whole query done, I just need some help with the where clause.

The psuedo code would be something like this

```
Case when @CustomerType = 'NEW'
THEN where cs.brandnewcustomer = 1

Case when @CustomerType = 'RECURRING'
THEN where cs.recurringcustomer= 1

Case when @CustomerType = 'REACTIVATED'
THEN where cs.reactivatedcustomer= 1

else case when @CustomerType = 'All' end
```

Does anyone have any tips on how to turn this into actual code?

Comment: You may go with the if condition, if(@customerType='new') begin select * from table where brandnewcustomer=1 end .. and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can form your conditions as:

```
WHERE (cs.brandnewcustomer = 1 AND @CustomerType = 'NEW')
      OR
      (cs.recurringcustomer = 1 AND @CustomerType = 'RECURRING')
      OR
      (cs.reactivatedcustome = 1 AND @CustomerType = 'REACTIVATED')
      OR
      (@CustomerType = 'ALL')
```

Comment: `or (@CustomerType = 'All')`

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yeah, just added. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Put this CASE statement in the WHERE clause:

```
select * from customers 
where 1 = case @CustomerType
    when 'NEW' then brandnewcustomer
    when 'RECURRING' then recurringcustomer
    when 'REACTIVATED' then reactivatedcustomer
    when 'All' then 1
  end
```

In case the parameter does not match any of the 4 values then nothing will be returned.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=73c8a1ecf72101eb16246d519d46ad4b).

Answer (score 0):

It would need to be structured like this:

```
SELECT ... FROM ...
WHERE cs.brandnewcustomer = CASE WHEN @CustomerType = 'NEW' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
AND cs.recurringcustomer = CASE WHEN @CustomerType = 'RECURRING' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
AND cs.reactivatedcustomer = CASE WHEN @CustomerType = 'REACTIVATED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
OR 1 = CASE WHEN @CustomerType = 'All' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Comment: Some of the other solutions work, but mine is the only one listed (so far) that enforces data integrity. If (by off chance), you have backing data that has a 1 for more than one type of customer, you will get a "first win" match with the others. With mine, none will win for data that is not accurate.

Answer (score 0):

I think this needs to be normalized

Customer types needs to be in a table with a primary key tb_CustomerType

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRnpx.png)

Customer table needs to have a foreign key to the customer type tb_Customer

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5F4L6.png)

you do not have to have a case statement if you have this kind of a table structure

Comment: while i agree the data needs to be normalized, your answer is not a solution and is more appropriately stated in a comment. i am surprised others have not down-voted your answer - as it doesn't meet the site criteria for a solution.

Comment: This could be taken as not a solution if the environment cannot be changed, but I do believe that what is correct path needs to be stated to let others think in a different angle to solutioning